# is there any way to do the below use case with ignite cache?

Tags: ignite

I am creating a site visitor counter.

1. site visitor counter per day by geographic location
2. previous day counter to be expired automatically and new counter initialised at 00 hour or first call for the day.
3. values to be store in the bucket where geo location is the key and counter is the value.
4. counters are to be automatic integers using an increment and get operation.
5. this bucket should be persisted in RDBMS.
6. Memcached provide all other option expect persistence.

I want to use only IgniteCache not ClientAtomicLong.
Below is the code example i am looking for

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("localhost:10800");
IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg);
ClientCache<String, Integer> clientCache = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache("mycache");
clientCache.increment("mykey", 0) // first argument is key and second is default value if not present. this method is not available with Ignite Client but equivalent feature is present in memcache netspy client.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post the code you have tried, as this site is for fixing specific programming problems.   Unfortunate the post reads like a request for the full thing to be done on Fivvr or some website.  Please update the question to be more specific so someone can fix a single problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do all of that. You'll need to bring together a few concepts.

1. You'll need to implement a custom [ExpiryPolicy](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/expiry-policies). All the built-in ones work for a duration rather than at a specific time
2. To atomically increment a value, there are a few ways you could do it. You could use an [entry processor](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/collocated-computations#entry-processor) or [transactions](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/key-value-api/transactions)
3. Ignite is memory-first, but can also [persist tables to disk](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/persistence/native-persistence). Or you can store in a third-party database

The key would obviously be the location. You could create your own representation or use the geospatial module.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. It looks good.  I am assuming this required to start ignite in client mode for doing this operation.Can we do the  the same with thin client as well.

Comment: You could use a thin-client. You would have to use transactions rather than an entry processor.